# How to query over specific value in dictionary in dynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table stored in dynamoDB which exemplary dictionary is the following:

```
 {event': 'A',
  'timestamp': '2017-10-15 16:20:47,009',
  'message': 'AAA'},
 {event': 'B',
  'timestamp': '2018-10-15 16:20:47,009',
  'message': 'BBB'},
 {event': 'A',
  'timestamp': '2019-10-15 16:20:47,009',
  'message': 'BBB'},
 {event': 'B',
  'timestamp': '2020-10-15 16:20:47,009',
  'message': 'AAA'},
```

I would like to do to things:

1. Query over timestamp - to have only dictionaries after year 2018
2. Query over message - to have only dictionaries for which `message == AAA`

Let's focus on querying over message:

I used the following code to load the table:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("dynamodb", region_name="eu-central-1")
session = boto3.Session(profile_name="myprofile")
resource = session.resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-central-1")
table = resource.Table("mytable")
```

The main problem I have is that when I'm running query code:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression="message = :message",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":message": "AAA"},
)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: event
```

I read something about this error, and people are saying that I can scan the table (which is impossible in my situation. since my whole table is enormous) or use secondary index (which unfortunately I couldn't understand what it means). Could you please give me a hand how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**

After answer I tried to do:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression="message = :message",
    FilterExpression="#ts >:timestamp",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":message": "AAA",
    ":timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:00"},
      ExpressionAttributeNames={
    "#ts": "timestamp"
  }
)
```

But I got the error: `ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: event`

Without usage of `ExpressionAtrributeNames` the error is identical

Comment: What is your table schema?

Comment: As I undersyand my table schema is `event`

Comment: Schema means, what is your partition and sort keys, or any indices that you have.

Comment: My partition key is `event` and sort key is `timestamp`

Answer (score 2):

To query a table in DynamoDB based on the value of a specific attribute, you need to specify that attribute in the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter of the `query` method.

The `KeyConditionExpression` parameter defines the conditions that the items in the table must meet in order to be returned by the query.

##### Your example

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression="message = :message",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":message": "AAA"},
)
```

In this sample, only items with a `message` attribute equal to `"AAA"` should be returned by the query.

##### Solution

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression="event = :event and message = :message",
    FilterExpression="#ts > :timestamp",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":event": "A",
        ":message": "AAA",
        ":timestamp": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#ts": "timestamp",
    },
)
```

This example shows you that:

1. `FilterExpression` parameter specifies that only items with a timestamp attribute that is greater than **"2018-01-01 00:00:00"** should be returned by the query. *(We changed `timestamp` keyword to `ts` for your error.)*
2. `KeyConditionExpression` parameter specifies that only items with **message** attribute equal to **"AAA"** and **event** attribute equal to **"A"** should be returned by the query.
3. `ExpressionAttributeValues` parameter defines the values that will be used in the `KeyConditionExpression` and `FilterExpression` parameters.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your comment and your help! When trying your code I received an error: `ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: timestamp`. Do you know why it is the case? ;))

Comment: Could you use `ts` instead of `timestamp`?  For ex.: `FilterExpression=" ts > :timestamp"`